# Is "nonversation" a word?

Tags: meaning, nouns, neologisms, is-it-a-word

Is there a word like "*nonversation*"?

Do people use this word in daily life? Where can it be used?

Comment: I've heard it from my friend. we're playing game and in that she spell it. Then she told me the meaning that nonversion means a meaningless conversation.

Comment: Sounds like a made-up word to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a "word" yet. It *could* be a word, shortly, if all goes well. It seems it's already being promoted as you can see under User-Submitted Words on Merriam-Webster: #1: [Nonversation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/top-ten-lists/top-10-user-submitted-words-vol-5/nonversation.html) in Top 10.

Then again, it may never make it to the OED, being "among the millions of '[non words](http://www.metro.co.uk/news/837166-wurfing-polkadodge-and-dringle-the-non-words-oxford-english-dictionary-rejected)' rejected for inclusion in the Oxford English Dictionary."

Comment: Hey thanks for this information, I didn't know that but from there i can find more new words.

Comment: Yeah, it's on Urban Dictionary too. But according to [this](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/7926646/Secret-vault-of-words-rejected-by-the-Oxford-English-Dictionary-uncovered.html), it was rejected by the OED.

Comment: @MrLister Edited in an epilog just now.

Comment: @Kris Some of those words are quite nice. I like "peppier".

Comment: *Precuperate* made me laugh out loud.

Answer (score 0):

You may have created it. I think it has good possibilities. You can use it, for example, when you're straining very hard to talk to someone who doesn't have much of anything to say. When you feel it's pointless to continue, you can say something like this:

> "**Excuse me, but I was hoping to have a stimulating *conversation* about warthogs, warlocks, and witches, not a *nonversation* filled with grunts, groans, and woeful sighs of vacuousness. Can you show me the way to go home? I'm tired and I want to go to bed.**"